# How to read a html file from another android app assets file?

Tags: java, android, html, webview, assets

I need to load html file in a webview component from another app assets files that contain a web site.
This is a call for my local folder, but I need to call from another app.
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/player/player.htm");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that probably you need to implement a content provider in the other app and thru that you could access the file. I don't see how you could access an other app's assets folder without any consent from the other app.